# To What Extent are Magnetism and Gravity Related and Unrelated?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity

I find many people (especially UFO-ologists) are quick to say there is an interplay between magnetism and gravity, especially when explaining antigravity of UFOs.

On the other side, I see those who are disciplined in science and  reasonably sceptical are quick to refute the relationship of the two forces.

Hence my question:

**To what extent are magnetism and gravity *related* and *unrelated*?**

I've already seen [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/120163/is-gravity-just-electromagnetic-attraction).

I'd like to know what modern science has to say between the both the **relationship** and **difference** between the two forces. A **summary**, some **formulas**, and **modern references** would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just for the record, in **the entirety of the current understanding of physics** the answer is absolutely that **there is utterly no relationship**, and you are very correct to point out that **people (eg ufologists etc) often -- absolutely mistakenly -- assume there is a connection**. Indeed, you hit on arguably one of the most common misunderstandings or mixups.

Comment: @JoeBlow  Yes, there is a connection, electromagnetic fields create (very weak) gravitational fields: http://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.93.024014